# Express serves static files from another server

Tags: node.js, express

Express can serve static local files like this:

```
app.use(express.static('public', STATIC_OPTIONS));
app.get('*', pageRendering);
```

When I go to `localhost/`, `pageRendering` will do its job.

Now I want to serve static files from another server, so I change the code to this:

```
app.use(proxy(url.parse('pathToRemoteServer')));
app.get('*', pageRendering);
```

When I go to `localhost/`, there is a conflict, and `pageRendering` won't get to do its job.

I don't want to change to `app.use('/public', proxy(url.parse('pathToRemoteServer')));` to avoid conflict.

Is there a way to fix this?

Edit: missing `var proxy = require('proxy-middleware');`

Comment: what is 'proxy' in this context?  A module or something you wrote?  Can you elaborate?  Also, this seems like a very good use case for using a web server as a reverse proxy, rather than cluttering your node logic.

Comment: what does "there is a conflict" mean?

Comment: @AlexWayne: conflicts with the path '/', I would have to change to app.use('/public',

Comment: Somewhere you HAVE to define which URLs are to be served by the other server and which by the Express server.  Right now, it appears you're sending all the URLs to your proxy.  A simple way ;to do that is to specify a path prefix such as `/static` and have only those go to the proxy.

Comment: @jfriend00: I did that with `/public`. But is there another way?

Comment: Well, some piece of code has to be able to tell whether a given request belongs to the proxy or not.  There are other ways to know that than a URL prefix (for example by extension or filename in the URL) or by using a different domain for static requests.

Comment: Best to use Nginx for this purpose!